# What might this gdb output mean?

Tags: iphone, gdb

Trying to create my first iPhone app that would play back audio. When I try to set up playback, messages like these appear in gdb:

> =shlibs-removed,shlib-info=[num="54",name="AudioIPCPlugIn",kind="B",dyld-addr="0x2c2000",reason="dyld",requested-state="E",state="E",path="/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/
>   Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn",
>   description="/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/
>   AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn",loaded_addr="0x2c2000",slide="0x2c2000",prefix=""]
>
> =shlibs-removed,shlib-info=[num="55",name="AppleHDAHALPlugIn",kind="B",dyld-addr="0x2cb000",reason="dyld",requested-state="E",state="E",path="/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/
>   AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn",
>   description="/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/
>   AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn",loaded_addr="0x2cb000",
>   slide="0x2cb000",prefix=""]

Not being familiar with gdb, I'm interested to know in general what sort of problems these types of messages might refer to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are informational messages from the system which let you know when a dynamic library gets unloaded from your executable.  I presume that they occur in this case because you are perhaps doing a bit too much destructing (ie, unloading bundles, etc.) when you try to shut down your app's connection to CoreAudio.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, those are information message about unloaded dynamic libraries, i don't think it denotes any problem or error.